# UDP packet to a Specific IP in LAN

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, udp, embedded

I have a embedded device in my LAN and a c++ application in Linux in a computer. I have made a UDP broadcast on my subnet broadcast address from C++ and my device returned a message with signature. Both of them have each others IP address now. I need to send a UDP packet from my C++ specifically to my device IP.
The initial call to my device was done over UDP, but it was using the broadcast option in socket options. 
Some of my experiments with packet generation tools gave me a impression that UDP uses MAC ID to find destination.
So what should be the method in C++, if I want to send a UDP packet to my specific IP in my LAN?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, check about the ISO stack to understand the difference between the MAC & the IP addresses, they're both used, though on the same physical medium (including radio wave) the MAC could be sufficient.
Also, have you given `boost::asio` a try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your response to stefaanv, it sounds like your question is really "how do I get the IP address from thread A to thread B?", where thread A receives the response to the broadcast message, and thread B does the device-specific communication.

One way you could do this is by creating thread B from thread A, and passing in the IP address as an argument to thread B's function.  This way thread B will know from the beginning what IP address to talk to.

If thread B has to be up and running before thread A, you can share the IP address using a global variable, and use, e.g. a semaphore so that thread A can tell thread B when it has set the IP address.  Just be sure that thread A is the only thread that writes that global variable, or else you will have to set up another layer of synchronization, e.g. using a mutex, to make sure that writing to the IP address is only done by one thread at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you send out a broadcast and you expect answers via UDP, you should receive them with the [recvfrom](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom) call.  This fills in the address of the sender.  The corresponding call to send UDP with the received address information is [sendto](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto).

Comment: The recvfrom is running on a separate thread. I need to capture data there and somehow share that data to the main thread. like to know weather this combo of 'recvfrom - sendto' will share the destination info,even if they are in different threads

Comment: If used as is, you can pass the the sockaddr to different threads together with the length parameter.  If needed, sockaddr can be parsed, use sockaddr_in from http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify O/S, but...

You can make a UDP socket use [connect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) if you want. This then means that further sends to that socket will go to the IP you "connected" to, all this despite UDP being connectionless.

Comment: OS is ubuntu, IDE code::Blocks and gnu 4.7.3
I am basically a Embedded Programmer learning PC programming
in C++ I created a socket, populated sockaddr_in with broadcast address, set broadcast options and send the packet(with my data buffer). My Device is listening to this port and it captures this UDP packet checks the signature and responds with its signature in the broadcast address itself. Upto that part seems OK,

Comment: but from now on I need to send data specifically to my destinations - no broadcasts. That is my idea.
I went through the connect idea on the above mentioned page. That idea seems to be Ok for me at least in the beginning as long as I have only one device in the network.
Would be more helpful if I can get some sample code! 
btw, so far I haven’t tried 'asio' I did some reading about it and somehow got the impression that it is for big network projects. Will be glad if I can get some inputs regarding the applicability of such libraries in project like this.
Thanks a lot